# Generating .grd files programmatically

Tags: javascript, php, gradient

I'm trying to generate `.grd` files in `Javascript` or `PHP`.
I googled a lot but I found that there is no way to do it yet!

I have gradient entries and I made it as PNG, CSS Code and SVG, And I want to convert one of these (or the original entries) into a .grd file that can let the visitors of the website download the gradient they want and then use it directly in Adobe Photoshop.

I found [this library](http://www.tonton-pixel.com/scripts/utility-scripts/generate-gradients-file/index.html) but it seems to not be for web. It's a Photoshop plugin programmed in `JS`.

After finding this library and it's made my `JS` that's mean it's possible to do it, and also it is going to be client side. That's cool.

- It's not problem for me if it's server-side or client-side.

Any Idea please?
Thank you all

Comment: Also: https://www.tonton-pixel.com/Photoshop%20Additional%20File%20Formats/gradients-file-format.html

Comment: @mario , The links you and Tarik provided are not for generating this type of files. these links provide a reading method, not generating it. Be sure before you close the question.

Comment: References are sufficient for "Any idea?" type of questions. You haven't thoroughly looked at either of the links. And looking for software/libraries is off-topic, anyway. Concrete attempts to program your own binary export (showcase minimal understanding) would make this on-topic and reopenable, of course.